# How can I vertically split divs evenly on a bootstrap web page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am building a responsive page using the following:
http://www.bootply.com/2sfiCehqac

What I need to happen is, so long as the screen is medium or large:
1) div_left and div_right (orange and blue) both need to each match the height of the image between them
2) div1 and div2 should evenly split the height of div_left, and div3 and div4 should evenly split the height of div_right

I have been able to achieve the desired effect using a table, but in doing so I lose the small-screen formatting which is already in place.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and testing I was able to piece together the following solution:

http://www.bootply.com/PISl9rq5Tc